# Mathematica Parallel computing with VMware Client

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, vmware, vdi

I have access to a virtual machine via vmware client and want to do parallel computing with mathematica (no direct www access on the vm).
But on the VM there's not mathematica installed and i don't want to buy an additinal one.
So I want to have the interface on my laptop and transfer as much computing as possible to the VM.

Following questions:
- Is it possible?
- How does it work?

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of *Mathematica's* native parallel computing capabilities does kind of depend on there being a *Mathematica* kernel running on each processing element (core, CPU, functional unit, whatever the heck they're called these days) in the gang so, without going outside *Mathematica*, you're dead in the water, it ain't possible.

On the other hand, you could use *Mathematica's* recently enhanced capabilities to play nicely with programs written in other languages (as long as those other languages are C) to write a back-end to run on the VM and call it from the *Mathematica* installation on your laptop.  And, of course, once you start writing in C, you can do all the parallelisation you want.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there's something like a basic, no-interface, pure computing mathematica programm free-of-charge or very cheap to install on the virtual machine. I assume the effort to do the C thing is quite high?

Comment: Hmmm, one rarely sees the terms *Mathematica* and *free-of-charge* in the same sentence.  I too would assume that the effort to implement a significant part of Mathematica's parallel computing capabilities in C would be quite high.